# how to use python regular expressions to pull any word that comes before or after a comma?

Tags: python, regex, string

How to use regular expressions in python to pull text that touches a comma?

For example

```
Str= "Select Name,Email,Contact (Select Subject,ActivityDate,Description from Opportunity) from Opportunity"

Desired_List = ['Name','Email','Contact','Subject','ActivityDate','Description']
```

Here's another string to test with:

```
Str = "Select Invoice_Number__c,ID,Name,Owner.Name,Amount,Billing_Email__c,Payment_Terms__c,Invoice_Schedule__c,Opt_Out_Date__c,CloseDate,Contract_Start_Date__c,Contract_End_Date__c,(Select Subject,ActivityDate,           Description from ActivityHistories ORDER By ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST)from Opportunity where StageName = 'Closed Won' ANDType != 'Upsell' ANDInvoice_Number__c != '' LIMIT 2"
```

Notice that there is a large space between the comma and Description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use positive lookahead and lookbehind to match words which border on the comma on either side.

```
import re

Str= "Select Name,Email,Contact (Select Subject,ActivityDate,Description from Opportunity) from Opportunity"

matches = re.findall(r"\w+(?=,)|(?<=,)\w+", Str)
print matches
```

Output:

```
['Name', 'Email', 'Contact', 'Subject', 'ActivityDate', 'Description']
```

These are documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Update: With the OP's new string:

```
['Invoice_Number__c', 'ID', 'Name', 'Owner', 'Name', 'Amount', 'Billing_Email__c', 'Payment_Terms__c', 'Invoice_Schedule__c', 'Opt_Out_Date__c', 'CloseDate', 'Contract_Start_Date__c', 'Contract_End_Date__c', 'Subject', 'ActivityDate', 'Description']
```

Comment: @JustinBarber, Fixed. I've been writing too much `C` recently. :)

Comment: I completely understand! Looks great now.

Comment: The issue is that when I run this, the last word isn't coming out for some reason. For example, this is the original String I'm working with, and 'Description' doesn't come out: "Select Invoice_Number__c,ID,Name,Owner.Name,Amount,Billing_Email__c,Payment_Terms__c,Invoice_Schedule__c,Opt_Out_Date__c,CloseDate,Contract_Start_Date__c,Contract_End_Date__c,(Select Subject,ActivityDate,Description from ActivityHistories ORDER By ActivityDate DESC NULLS LAST)from Opportunity where StageName = 'Closed Won' ANDType != 'Upsell' ANDInvoice_Number__c != '' LIMIT 2".

Comment: @Chris, Please update your question instead with the sample string. It is difficult to even see where one string ends and another begins in the comment.

Comment: @Chris, What version of Python are you running on? Description comes out for me. See the update with new output.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the issue being that when there is a large space between the comma and Description. For example, try again with the above text. Is there a way to get around the fact that there may be a large space between the word and the comma? If not, this definitely answers my original question.